# Any Java math library allowing vectorization and broadcasting the way numpy does?

Tags: java, numpy

One thing I find very confortable with Numpy is the vectorization of operations with arrays (ie. the absence of any explicit looping), and the implicit element-by-element behavior of operations.

Since I have to move from Python to Java for a project, I was looking for any equivalent in well known math libraries (Colt, JScience, Apache Commons Math). But as far as I see it, none of them have equivalent capabilities.
Could anyone advise me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem as you but did not find a java solution. Java misses operator overloading for `[]` and has no slices. So you will not find a Java solution with the same, easy to read notation as numpy provides.

Answer (score 1):

The [nd4j library](https://deeplearning4j.org/docs/latest/nd4j-overview) is essentially "NumPy for Java".  It supports broadcasting and vector operations.